# Iterate over nested sublists and remove specific items

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a beginner in Python. Can someone help me figure out what is the problem in my code below in python 2.7:

I am trying to iterate through list and sublists recursively and delete AND, OR, NOT, IFF, IMPLIES in list.

My method :

```
def setOfSets(prop):
    if isinstance(prop, str):
        answer = prop
    else:
        for item in prop:
            if isinstance(item, str):
                if (item == IFF):
                    answer = prop.remove(item)
                if (item == IMPLIES):
                    answer = prop.remove(item)
                if (item == AND):
                    answer = prop.remove(item)
                if (item == OR):
                    answer = prop.remove(item)
                if (item == NOT):
                    answer = prop.remove(item)
            else:
                answer = setOfSets(item)   

    return answer

prop0 = setOfSets(inputList)
print "Set of Sets:"
print prop0
```

Results :

```
Input : ['or', 'R', ['not', 'B'], 'W']
Expected output : ['R',['B'],'W']
Current output : None
```

I think I am making some silly mistake or using something wrong in python.

Comment: `answer = setOfSets(item)`

Comment: I added else:
            answer = setOfSets(item) still getting None

Comment: Then, 1. You need to fix the indentation of your code 2. Show the actual code which invokes `setOfSets`

Comment: `list.remove` will not return the removed item, but `None`. Perhaps you meant `list.pop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simpler to build a new list than to copy the old nested list and remove items from it.

Here's a slightly improved version, with more test cases:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

OPNAMES = set(('IFF', 'IMPLIES', 'AND', 'OR', 'NOT'))

def setOfSets(prop):
    answer = []
    for item in prop:
        if isinstance(item, str):
            if item.upper() not in OPNAMES:
                answer.append(item)
        else:
            answer.append(setOfSets(item))

    return answer

def test(prop):
    print prop
    print setOfSets(prop)
    print

props = [
    ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    ['or', 'R', ['not', 'B'], 'W'],
    ['or', 'R', ['not', 'B'], [['IMPLIES', 'Q'], 'W'], 'Z'],
    [['A', 'AND', ['B', 'OR', ['NOT', 'C']], 'IFF', 'D'],'IMPLIES', 'Z'],
]

for prop in props:
    test(prop)
```

**output**

```
['A', 'B', 'C']
['A', 'B', 'C']

['or', 'R', ['not', 'B'], 'W']
['R', ['B'], 'W']

['or', 'R', ['not', 'B'], [['IMPLIES', 'Q'], 'W'], 'Z']
['R', ['B'], [['Q'], 'W'], 'Z']

[['A', 'AND', ['B', 'OR', ['NOT', 'C']], 'IFF', 'D'], 'IMPLIES', 'Z']
[['A', ['B', ['C']], 'D'], 'Z']
```

Comment: As a more efficient way you can use `set` for `{'IFF', 'IMPLIES', 'AND', 'OR', 'NOT'}` !

Comment: @Kasra: Good call. I'm still using Python 2.6.6, so I've used the older set syntax in my modified code.